# paste(x,collapse="\n") doesn't work? (R code)

Tags: r, paste

Hope someone can help me understand this basic anomaly of line separation:

```
a<-c("a","b","c") 
a
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
paste(a,collapse="\n")
# [1] "a\nb\nc"
```

basically, I have a data frame like:

```
       a  b
1      6  228
2     10  148
3     20  124
4     34  165
5    100  165
6    200  165
7    310  165
```

and I use `paste(data_frame_name$b,collapse= "\n")`, but I get

```
[1] "228\n148\n124\n165\n165\n165\n165"
```

What can be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: the same answer but in different lines and without the "n"s in the middle

Comment: Then see @MatthewLundberg's answer below. `print()` escapes all special characters (including newlines) and `print()` is what implicitly runs to display a value from a function call.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're looking for `cat`:

```
cat(paste(a,collapse="\n"))
a
b
c
```

`print` is called to print an object when you type its name:

```
print(paste(a,collapse="\n"))
[1] "a\nb\nc"
```

Comment: Thanks! Although, I don't see the reason why without cat() it won't work? collapse= "\n" is the key here...am I wrong?

Comment: It's the difference in how `cat` presents a string, compared to `print`.  The newlines are embedded in each case, but displayed differently.