# Loop over words in a string

Tags: r

I got a string like this

```
line <- "I got a string"
```

What I would like to do now is loop over the words in this string. Therefore I do:

```
list = strsplit(line, " ")
```

Now I would like to loop over it like this:

```
for(i in list){
 print(i)
}
```

But now it just prints the whole sentence while I am looking for

```
I

got

a 

string
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Comment: You really should not name your variable `list`. The code is working: it prints a vector of 4 words, not the whole string. If you want to go to the next line after each word you could replace `list` by `unlist(list)` in the loop. But really, rename your variable.

Comment: You should check the structure of `list` using `str(list)`. You want `for(i in list[[1]]){
  print(i)
}`.

Comment: `cat(paste(unlist(list), collapse = "\n"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [paste(x,collapse="\n") doesn't work? (R code)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725725/pastex-collapse-n-doesnt-work-r-code)

Answer (score 2):

`strsplit` can take a vector of inputs ex:

```
> strsplit(c("I have a string","I have one too"), " ")
[[1]]
[1] "I"       "have"    "a"       "string"

[[2]]
[1] "I"    "have" "one"  "too"
```

In order to keep the outputs separate, `strsplit` puts each of the outputs into a list, and to keep the outputs consistant, it still outputs a list even if it is given a vector of length 1.

```
> strsplit("I have a string", " ")
[[1]]
[1] "I"       "have"    "a"       "string"
```

As a result,your `for` loop is only indexing into the first level of your data, the list element of length 1.  This means the value of `i` gets set to:

```
[1] "I"       "have"    "a"       "string"
```

If you want to index into the actual string vector, you need to use one of the suggestion in the comments, either simplifying the list elements into a vector using `unlist` as @etienne suggested.

```
for(i in unlist(list)){ print(i) }
```

Or indexing into the first element of your list when you are assigning the indexes of your `for` loop as @Roland suggested:

```
for(i in list[[1]]){ print(i) }
```

For your purposes, these two options will produce the same results, but there will be a difference if you give `strsplit` a vector longer than length 1.  In that case the `unlist` option will concatenate all of the list together into one vector which you will loop over, where as the `list[[1]]` option will just loop over the first string.